# Is GCLatencyMode.LowLatency a good choice?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, garbage-collection

I have a C# windows service acting as a server, the service holds some large (>8Gb) data structures in memory and exposes search methods to clients via remoting.

The avg search operation is executed in <200ms and the service handles up to 20 request/sec.

I'm noticing some serious performance degradation (>6000ms) on a regular basis for few seconds

My best guess is that the server threads are stopped by a gen2 garbage collection from time to time.

I'm considering switching from server gc to workstation gc and wrap my search method in this to prevent GC during requests.

```
 static protected void DoLowLatencyAction(Action action)
    {
        GCLatencyMode oldMode = GCSettings.LatencyMode;
        try
        {
            GCSettings.LatencyMode = GCLatencyMode.LowLatency;
            // perform time-sensitive actions here
            action();
        }
        finally
        {
            GCSettings.LatencyMode = oldMode;
        }
    }
```

Is this a good idea?

Under what conditions the GC will be performed anyway inside the low latency block?

Note: I'm running on a x64 server with 8 cores

Thanks

Comment: Don't guess at the cause. Use a profiler, performance counters, logging, etc to figure out what the actual problem is.

Comment: Yep. I used performace counters and logging and it is GC time.

Answer (score 10):

I've not used `GCLatencyMode` before so cannot comment on whether using it is a good idea or not.

However, are you *sure* you are using server GC? By default, Windows services use workstation GC.

I've had a similar problem before in a Windows service, and setting server GC mode using:

```
<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <gcServer enabled="true" />
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

in the service's `app.config` file solved it.

Have a read of [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/tess/archive/2008/04/17/how-does-the-gc-work-and-what-are-the-sizes-of-the-different-generations.aspx) from Tess Ferrandez's blog for a more details.

Answer (score 3):

I am surprised that your search method even trigger a GC, if the 8GB datastructure is static ( not modified a lot by adding or removing from it ), and all you do is searching it, then you should just try to avoid allocating temporary objects within your search method ( if you can ). Creating objects is the thing that triggers a GC, and if you have a data structure that is rarely modified, then it makes sense to avoid the GC all together ( or delay it as much as possible ).

GCSettings.LowLatency does is it gives a hint to the GC to do eager collections such that we can avoid Gen2 collections while the LowLatency mode is set. What this does as a side effect is make the GC eager to collect outside the region where LowLatency mode is set, and could result in lower performance ( in this case you can try server GC mode ).

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't sound like a great idea. At some point the GC will ignore your hint and do the collection anyway.

I believe you will have much better success by actually profiling and optimizing your service. Run [PerfView](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28567) (free, awesome, Microsoft tool) on your server while it is running. See who owns troublesome objects and how long specific long running GC events are taking.